# How to get hex hash with crypt() function?

Tags: c, hash, sha256, crypt

If i create a SHA-256 has in the terminal i get a nice looking hex hash:

```
echo -n ChillyWilly | sha256sum
4c74e3994a247dfc31a515721528c78bb6ec09ccdcfd894d09f4aa44131393a8  -
```

If i try to do the same with the [crypt(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) function then i get something entirely different:

```
const char* what = crypt("ChillyWilly", "$5$");
printf("%s\n", what);
$5$$fQITOGYPwBrwOSpjX1Uhx5Ock/J84zbrqmTtg/SlvMB
```

It looks like Base64 but it's not.

My assumption is that if the key and salt are equal then i should get the same result. All SHA-256 hashers in the web will generate the same result from the same key/salt combination.

How can i get the same hex hash with the crypt(3) function? I have set the $5$ as instructed on the  [crypt manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) that should force the crypt function into SHA-256 mode.

I know there are a few similar questions here but they did not seem to contain the correct answers.

Thanks!

Comment: You want `sha256` to generate the same hash as `crypt`?  Why?  They're different algorithms.

Comment: The manpage warning on `crypt` is funny. "Exhaustive searches of this key space are possible using massively parallel computers.". We'd call that an iGPU these days, and consider them unsuitable for serious gaming :D. There's a reason we moved to `sha256`.

Comment: Yes, i did expect the same result. That's what the $5$ is there for. This should force the crypt function to generate a SHA256 hash. Assuming that the key and salt are the same i should get the same result.

Comment: @elelont Ah, I see now.  Yes, this makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crypt()` will in fact use the same SHA-256 algorithm - but it does not return the hash as you would expect. After computing the hash it does it applies another transformation to the result, [as seen here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/sha256-crypt.c#L337).

So I wouldn't count on using it and getting the same result as `sha256sum`, since it's built for a different [purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)). You might look into using the [openssl SHA256](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SHA256.html) implementation, or something else if you need it to match.

Answer (score 4):

While `crypt` can use SHA-256 when in `$5$` mode, they aren't the same thing.

SHA-256 is a hash function, designed to run quickly. But `crypt` is a key-derivation function intended for hashing passwords. As such, it runs SHA-256 a large number of times (5000 by default) to make it slower and less prone to brute-force attacks. So it will give a different result than a simple SHA-256 use. You can see the details of the algorithm [here](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt).

As you saw, `crypt` also doesn't output the result as hex, but as a Base64-like encoding (not the standard Base64 but based on a similar idea). There's no point in trying to convert to hex if you do this expecting to get the same result as SHA-256.